# GridView/ObjectDataSource inside runat=server container does not bind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, objectdatasource

I've got a small web form with 2 radio buttons, call them PickFromList and EnterValue.  When PickFromList is checked I want to show a GridView that I've configured to bind to an ObjectDataSource.  When EnterValue is checked I want the GridView to disappear.

This form is laid out using a table and want to hide/show the appropriate rows based on appropriate data and user input.

Unfortunately the GridView doesn't bind when the trPickFromList2 row specifies the id and the runat="server" attributes.  If I remove id and runat="server" from the trPickFromList2 row it binds successfully.

Any ideas?

```
<table id="tblOptions" runat="server">
    <tr id="trPickFromList1" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbFromList" runat="server" GroupName="Selection" 
                Text="Get Data From Existing Item" AutoPostBack="True" 
                oncheckedchanged="rbromList_CheckedChanged" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trPickFromList2" runat="server">
        <td style="padding-left:20px">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="odsList" Width="400px" onrowdatabound="gvList_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    ...
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trEnterValue1" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbEnterValue" runat="server" GroupName="Selection" 
                            Text="Create a New Item"
                            AutoPostBack="True" 
                            oncheckedchanged="rbEntered_CheckedChanged" />
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just show/hide the TRs with javascript? That way you won't have this problem and you'll have a much more responsive UI.

With jQuery:

$('.classOnShowRadioButton').click(function(){
    $('.trToShow').show();
    $('.trToHide').hide();
});

then obviously do the reverse for the other radio button.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  There's no good reason, just that we're not a big JavaScript shop.  There are some additional problems, such as validation errors on postback that would have to be handled too.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up implementing [Wilco Bauwer's RowSelectorField control](http://www.wilcob.com/Wilco/News/RowSelectorFieldForGridView.aspx) to solve this problem.  It's not a perfect solution in that the control surfaces the the selected row's index value rather than the selected data key value(s); however, it worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. not quite sure but something which has got me a few times is have the AutoWireEvents set to false, its at the top in the <% page /%> section. sorry if it's no help, but something annoying and insignificant like that is prob the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the AutoWireEvents answer Joe suggested is not the issue, you could also try removing the runat=server from the tr tags, and instead wrap them with placeholders and use the placeholders to control visibility. (Note, don't use panels, as it will result in invalid html)

Answer (score 0):

I [noticed the same behavior](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/formview-no-update-inside-run-at-server-table-control/) with a FormView inside a TR tag with runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you're using a table for layout? Try taking all your controls out of the table, and make the radio buttons just make the actual GridView visible/invisible.

Comment: Just for alignment purposes - 20px in to subordinate the grid to the radio button.

Comment: The reason I ask is because you're turning your TR into a server object in order to show/hide it. But your GridView is already a server object and you are able to show/hide it by itself. The only caveat to doing this is the TR will still be rendered (empty). Without the table it's cleaner.